# Turn array of objects into array of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having a real brain freeze moment here. I have an array of objects that I need to convert into just an array of properties. What would be the best approach to turn this;

```
[
  {
    user_id: 302
  },
  {
    send_user_email: true
  },
  {
    send_admin_email: true
  }
]
```

into this;

```
[
  user_id: 302,
  send_user_email: true,
  send_admin_email: true
]
```

Comment: That array doesn't look valid.

Comment: If you're referring to something like `associative arrays` in `PHP`, they don't exist in `JavaScript`, therefore something like `[user_id: 302]` is **not a valid array** in `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Object.assign`:

```js
const array = [
  {
    user_id: 302
  },
  {
    send_user_email: true
  },
  {
    send_admin_email: true
  }
];

const result = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(result);
```